# Run Windows service with Java

Tags: java, service

I need to run Windows service with my parameter (token). I know how to start service:

```
String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "net", "start", "service name"};
new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
```

But don't know how to start it with my parameters?

Comment: add the parameter in the command object?

Answer (score 1):

A simple Java based utility to either start or stop a service could be something like this.

```
public static boolean stopService(final String serviceName) {
    return execCommand("cmd.exe", "/c", "net", "stop", "\"" + serviceName + "\"");
}

public static boolean startService(final String serviceName) {
    return execCommand("cmd.exe", "/c", "net", "start", "\"" + serviceName + "\"");
}

private static boolean execCommand(final String... args) {
    try {
        Process process = new ProcessBuilder(args)
        .redirectErrorStream(true)
        .start();

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
            String output = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
            System.out.println("Command output:: " + output);
        }

    process.waitFor();
    return process.exitValue() == 0;
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that the `execCommand` method can be used to run basically any command. Also, if not really necessary I would recommend using `sc` to manage services instead of `net`.

Also the reason that this was not working for you, was that you where passing in the service name wrong.